# Swift variable still 0 after assigning it a value?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

in my viewDidLoad() i print out a the result of a function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("top count = \(getCurrentOrderNum())")
}
```

The function computes the value likes so

```
func getCurrentOrderNum() -> Int{
    var orderNum = 0
    ref = Firebase(url: "urlhiddenforprivacy")
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let count = snapshot.childrenCount
            orderNum = Int(count)
    })
    return orderNum
}
```

Yet it still prints 0? I tried to put var orderNum: Int = Int() at the top of my code instead of inside my getCurrentOrderNum function, but that didn't work. I know it gets the correct value inside my ref.observe function because when I ran this... it printed out the right value

```
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let count = snapshot.childrenCount
            orderNum = Int(count)
            print(orderNum) //*****THIS PRINTS THE RIGHT VALUE****
    })
    return orderNum
}
```

Comment: Is `observeSingleEventOfType` an asynchronous operation by any chance? I suppose it is... that's your issue, then.

Comment: Idk what that means honestly, but how do I fix it if it is an asynchronous operation?

Comment: like Eric D says : `observeSingleEventOfType` is a block and seems to be async. So before your block finishes, you return. That's why you always print 0

Comment: I tried to return it before it finishes but the block is a void function so it cannot return anything :/

Comment: Daniels answer will work, but I think your code may be overcomplicating things. may I ask what  the order number is used for and when is it needed? I am asking as when your app starts you can observe the order number to get an initial value. Then, whenever it's updated by any client, your app could automatically be notified there was a change; instead of polling for it, the order number will always be accurate. Also, you may want to change basing your order number on childCount as there are better solutions - that can be addressed in an answer once we have more info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are returning `orderNum` from the method `getCurrentOrderNum()` before the asynchronous block actually runs. So at the time of return, `orderNum` is still `0`, the initial value you set. The block completes later.

Your best option is probably to change the method to:

```
func getCurrentOrderNum(callback:Int->()) {
    var orderNum = 0
    ref = Firebase(url: "urlhiddenforprivacy")
    ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        let count = snapshot.childrenCount
        orderNum = Int(count)
        callback(orderNum)
    })
}
```

And you would then call it like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getCurrentOrderNum { orderNum in print(orderNum) }
}
```

This changes the `getCurrentOrderNum()` method to call back to a closure once it has finished retrieving the right value.

**UPDATE**: Based on comment below, the goal is to do something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->Int { 
    return getCurrentOrderNum() 
}
```

Here is an asynchronous approach for doing that:

```
class YourViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

    private var orderNumber:Int = 0
    private IBOutlet var tableView:UITableView!

    func getCurrentOrderNum(callback:Int->()) {
        ref = Firebase(url: "urlhiddenforprivacy")
        ref.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
            let count = snapshot.childrenCount
            callback(Int(count))
        })
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCurrentOrderNum {
            orderNum in
            //This code runs after Firebase returns the value over the network
            self.orderNumber = orderNum  // Set our orderNumber to what came back from the request for current order number
            self.tableView.reloadData()  // Now reload the tableView so it updates with the correct number of rows
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    
        return self.orderNumber // When the view first loads, this will be 0 and the table will show nothing.  After the request to Firebase returns the value, this will be set to the right number, the table view will be reloaded, and it will call this method again to get the updated number of rows to display.
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never used something like that? How do I assign a variable to the result of the function? something like this - orderNum = getCurrentOrderNum()

Comment: this is what i want to do 
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->Int{
        return getCurrentOrderNum()
    }

Comment: @LukePatterson Since the result isn't available at the moment you want to assign getCurrentOrderNum() to the variable, you would have to move all the code that depends on having that result into the callback block, like this:

getCurrentOrderNum { 
    orderNum in
    let nextOrder = orderNum + 1
    // do other stuff with the orderNum now that we have it
}

The other option is to make your whole app just pause at the point you want to get the orderNum until it is retrieved from Firebase and it can proceed with assigning the value. But that is a bad user experience and bad practice.

Comment: @LukePatterson Regarding the tableView data source method, keep in mind that at the moment the table view asks for the number of rows, your app does not yet know how many there should be.  To get the orderNum from FireBase, is needs to send a request through the network and get a response.  That could be 100ms or several seconds of waiting, who knows? But the table view expects an immediate response. I'll update my answer with an approach for what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

In general using Firebase to return function results can be tricky - it's taking an asynchronous process and squeezing it into a synchronous process. While it can be done (as shown by Daniels good answer) there are alternatives. By looking at the code in the question, there may be a couple of important Firebase concepts that may have been overlooked.

I want to present a super simple asynchronous solution that leverages the power of Firebase.

Here's some conceptual stuff:

Define a var to keep track of the order number -

```
var currentOrderNumber = Int
```

Firebase structure

```
orders
  order_id_00
    order_num: 12345
  order_id_01
    order_num: 12346
```

Set up an observer on the orders node in viewDidLoad to notify the app when a new order is added. This will occur any time an order is written to the node so then all of the clients know what the current order numbers is:

```
ref.queryOnOrdersNode.childAdded { snapshot in

  if let orderNumber = snapshot.value["order_num"] as? Int {
     currentOrderNumber = orderNumber
  }

}
```

and from then on whenever currentOrderNumber is printed, it will contain the actual currentOrderNumber.

It's pretty cool in that you are letting Firebase do the heavy lifting; instead of polling Firebase over and over to get the currentOrderNumbers, Firebase will tell your app what the current order number is when it changes.

You can expand on this to populate a tableView and keep it updated with additions.

firebase structure

```
people
  person_id_0
     name: "Bill"
  person_id_1
     name: "Larry"
```

and the code to populate an array and add an observer for future additions:

```
var namesArray = [String]

peopleNode.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { snapshot in

    if let name = child.value["name"] as? String {
       namesArray.append(name)
       self.tableView.reloadData
    }  
}
```

and the tableView delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)->Int { 
    return peopleArray.count
}
```

Again, this lets Firebase do the heavy lifting; you don't have to poll for data as when a new person is added to the people node, Firebase tells your app and the tableView is automatically updated.

You'll notice that the code is super short and tight because your letting Firebase do most of the work for you keeping your variables updated and table populated with fresh data.

(there are typos in this code as it's conceptual)